# comparing files against original file with different number of rows

Tags: file, unix, awk, compare, row

I have set of files, 1 answers file and few results files
I need to compare each of the results file with answers, but the result files may not have the same number or rows.

answer file

```
q1, true
q2, false
q3, false
q4, true
q5, true
```

results 1

```
q1, true
q2, false
q3, true
```

table I would like to have

```
q1, 1
q2, 1
q3, 0
q4, 0
q5, 0
```

so if the data does match then its 1 else its 0 and if the row does not exist consider it as 0 again --- the same action should happen for all the files in the result folder.

What I tried so far :

```
awk -F "," '{print $0}' answer.csv | grep -f - result01.csv > me.csv
```

which prints the correct answers only

and is there a chance to do the same if the data for results look like the following?

results 1

```
data/q1, true
data/q2, false
data/q3, true
```

Comment: Do you want us to do your homeworks ?  =)

Comment: @75inchpianist: I have this so far `awk -F "," '{print $0}' answer.csv | grep -f - result01.csv > me.csv` which prints the correct asnwers only

Comment: Always put your search in your questions

Comment: @sputnick: No, its not a homework, I have processes a lot of results and seems to me it would be easier to check them with unix than excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` to compare the results file `r` against the answer `a` file:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{print $1,a[$1]==$2;next}{print $1,0}' r a
q1, 1
q2, 1
q3, 0
q4, 0
q5, 0
```

Comment: I managed to get the results but there is a problem when I am trying to replay "r" with "result.csv"

Comment: I would guess from the extension `.csv` and your later added own attempt using `-F","` that your actual files are different from the ones posted *e.g* `q1,true` **not** `q1 true`!?

Comment: this is what it works for now but can't make it work the way you mentioned `awk 'FNR==NR{r[$1]=$2;next}$1  {print $1,r[$1]==$2?1:0;next}{print $1,0}' result01.csv answer.csv > me01.csv `

Comment: each time I replace the r and a with result01.csv and answer.csv I get a syntax error on the "."

Comment: What version of `awk` do you have? Even with your changed input file this script still works.

Comment: this is how I am making it work but I would still like to learn about the R `FILES="test/*" for X in $FILES
do name=$(basename $X) awk 'FNR==NR{X[$1]=$2;next}$1 {print $1,X[$1]==$2?1:0;next}{print $1,0}' $X answer.csv > ${name}         
done`

Comment: Glad you have it work now. I'm not sure what you mean about the `R`? `r` is just the name of the file I gave `result01.csv`.

Comment: I was facing problems replacing r with result.csv ... it was giving syntax error

Comment: You can replace `a[$1]==$2?1:0` with just `a[$1]==$2`

Comment: my file name is answer.csv and result01.csv but then I replay those in the line I get errors and its not working in BASH :(

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`comm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?comm) command which can be used to compare two sorted files line by line.

For example:

```
$ comm  -2  <(sort answerFile) <(sort resultFile)
        q1 true
        q2 false
q3 false
q4 true
q5 true
```

The first column contains lines unique to file1 and the second column contains lines common to both files.

Comment: To get the desired output, pipe into `awk '{print $1, /^[[:space:]]/}'`